# A comma separated list from two li elements

Tags: javascript, html

I would need help to move forward with my code. I want each time the user writes (,) between two words, they should be separated and form two li elements in a list. Right now the whole code works but I would get tips on how to make a comma separated text.

```
   var names = [];
  function convert_to_list()
  {

    var theName = document.getElementById("enter").value;
    if (theName == "" || theName.length == 0)
    {
       return false; //stop the function since the value is empty.
    }
    names.push(theName);
    document.getElementById("converted_list").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>"+names[names.length-1]+"</li>";
  }
    

<form>
    <fieldset>
    
        <textarea id="enter" onkeyup=""></textarea> 
         <input onclick="convert_to_list()"value="Konvertera" type="button"/>
                    
         <div id="converted_list"><ul></ul></div>
                
      </form>
       </fieldset>
```

Comment: put the above comment in post

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like I did in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Lingertje/pen/GRWKaMa).

Use the `split` function to split a string when it encounters a specified character, in your case a comma.

The HTML (pug) would look like this:

```
form
  label 
    span seperated list
    input#js-seperatedList(type="text")
    
ul.results
```

And this will be your JavaScript code:

```
const inputValue = document.querySelector('#js-seperatedList')
const results = document.querySelector('.results');

inputValue.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  results.innerHTML = ''
  const res = e.target.value.split(",")
  
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += 1) {
    const e = document.createElement('li');
    e.innerHTML = res[i]
    results.appendChild(e)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` function to separate the words using comma and then `create li element` and append into final ul element.

```js
const btnEnter = document.getElementById("btnEnter");
btnEnter.addEventListener("click", convert_to_list);
const ulElements = document.getElementById("converted_list").children[0];

function convert_to_list() {
  const theName = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  if (theName.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  const list = theName.split(",");
  const liElements = [];
  for (const value of list) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = value.trim();
    ulElements.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
    
        <textarea id="enter" onkeyup=""></textarea> 
         <input id="btnEnter" value="Konvertera" type="button"/>
                    
         <div id="converted_list"><ul></ul></div>
                
       </fieldset> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using addEventListener which is much simpler than calling functions inside html elements , and to do what you asking the split() method can do that with any string , if there is something you don't understand with this code i am happy to help

```
document.querySelector('.btnclick').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const theName = document.getElementById('enter').value;

      if (theName.includes(',')) {
        theName.split(',').map(function (e) {
          if (e !== '')
            return document
              .querySelector('#converted_list')
              .insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li>${e}</li>`);
        });
      } else if (theName !== '' || theName.length !== 0) {
        document
          .querySelector('#converted_list')
          .insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li>${theName}</li>`);
      }
    });
  <form>
    <fieldset>

      <textarea id="enter" onkeyup=""></textarea>
      <input  class="btnclick" value="Konvertera" type="button" />

      <div id="converted_list">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("form").onclick=(ev,v)=>{
 if (ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON") {
   ev.preventDefault();
   v=ev.target.previousElementSibling.value.trim();
   ev.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML=(v>""?"<li>"+v.replaceAll(",","</li><li>")+"</li>":"");
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea id="enter" onkeyup=""></textarea> 
    <button>Konvertera</button>            
    <div id="converted_list"><ul></ul></div>               
  </fieldset> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```